# JSON lookup by initial or top level value

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to be able to lookup a JSON property using -

```
countries['us']
```

and have returned an object such as

```
{
  flag : 'us-flag.png',
  capital : 'Washington DC',
  anthem : 'Pump Up The Jam'
}
```

etc.

Is it possible to combine an array and objects in such a way? So that the JSON might look something like -

```
"countries" : [
  "us" : {
      flag : "us-flag.png",
      capital : "Washington DC",
      anthem : "Pump Up The Jam"
  }
]
```

I hope this makes sense. In short can I use an array to do a lookup in JSON?

Thanks

Comment: countries['us'] will work even if it's not an array (an object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your notation is slightly off. In JSON, an object is a set of key/value pairs. The value can be another object (i.e. another set of key/value pairs). This allows you to do:

```
"countries" : {
  "us" : {
    "flag" : "us-flag.png",
    "capital" : "Washington DC",
    "anthem" : "Pump Up The Jam"
  },
  "ru" : {
   ...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, arrays are a collection of values. These values can also be objects:

```
"countries" : [
  {
    "flag" : "us-flag.png",
    "capital" : "Washington DC",
    "anthem" : "Pump Up The Jam"
  },
  {
   ...
  }
]
```

However, it is incorrect for an array to have key/value pairs.

See http://www.json.org/ for additional details.

Comment: Thanks zkhr for your more kindly and indepth answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what an object does.
The only difference between an object and an array us that arrays have numeric indices.